# How can I make a vector with all the video modes in SFML?

Tags: c++, vector, syntax-error, sfml

I have this:

```
std::vector <sf::VideoMode> *screenResolution = new std::vector<sf::VideoMode>;

*screenResolution = sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes();

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < screenResolution->size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << screenResolution[i]->width << ":" << screenResolution[i]->height <<std::endl;
}
```

And for some reason an error appears in the cout that says "the expresion must be a type of pointer".

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to a std::vector / dynamically allocate your vector?

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you `new`ing that vector? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: You're over complicating things. `for (const auto& mode : sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes()) std::cout << mode.width << ":" << mode.height << '\n';` seems to be what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to carefuly read error message. Your vector is of `sf::VideoMode` which doesn't look like pointer. Only `->` can dereference pointers, so you can't use it in your loop. You also probably don't need dynamic allocation for your vector.

The following code should work for you:

```
std::vector<sf::VideoMode> screenResolution = sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes();

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < screenResolution.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << screenResolution[i].width << ":" << screenResolution[i].height << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: But screenResolution[i]. doesn't have width if I use a dot.

Comment: Of course `sf::VideoMode` has `width` and `height`, but problem is with your way of accessing vector. See my edited answer or [original documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php).

Comment: That is why I asked why you needed to dynamically allocate the vector. It's unusual to need/want to do that.